# How to configure loopback for switch management

Tags: cisco, vlan, bgp, vrf, loopback

We have Cisco Switches (Nexus 93). My PC is on vxlan, in vrf "test" with default gateway 60.254.
We want to use loopback 99 for managent for switches. We have created a loopback 99 with an IP address on each switch: switch 1 - 10.12.33.11/32, switch 2 - 33.22/32, switch 3 - 33.33/32, switch 4 - 33.44/32 with vrf "test".
I am trying to ping them, but I can only ping 33.11 and 33.33. Vrf "test" is being distributed by BGP route reflector, it works fine.
Maybe I should assing a VLAN on loopback 99?
Or assign a second IP address in 60 vxlan with 60.254 gateway?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would only use a loopback for layer-3 switches that have routing enabled because you must route to and from the loopback interface.

Layer-2 switches use an SVI and default gateway for management because there is no routing on a layer-2 switch to be able to reach a loopback interface.